# Sqlalchemy: Find row in which record is located

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

What should I add to my code so it prints in which row of the table is the username located `if exist == True :` ? It can also return the id of the record as it would show me its position in the table. I did not include the database code because I think that it is not necessary. Sorry for my bad explanation English is not my native language.

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///sqlalchemy_login.db')
Base.metadata.bind = engine

DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = DBSession()



username_attempt = raw_input('Enter username:')
username_attempt = unicode(username_attempt)

exist = session.query(exists().where(user.username == username_attempt)).scalar()


while exist == False :
    print 'Incorrect username'
    username_attempt = raw_input('Enter username:')
    username_attempt = unicode(username_attempt)
    exist = session.query(exists().where(user.username == username_attempt)).scalar()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sqlalchemy supports `select` statement queries.  So I would do something like:

```
def _get_users(attempt):
    stmt = sqlalchemy.select([users]).where(users.c.username == attempt)
    return [dict(r) for r in sqlalchemy.execute(stmt)]

def _get_attempt():
    username_attempt = raw_input('Enter username:')
    return unicode(username_attempt) 

attempt = _get_attempt()
recs = _get_users(attempt)

while not recs:
    print 'Incorrect username'
    attempt = _get_attempt()
    recs = _get_users(attempt)
print recs
```

When recs is not empty (and a valid username has been given), recs will contain a list of dictionaries representing the rows in the table.  You can traverse `recs` and get the `id` of each row.

Note: you will need to define `users` table:

```
db_metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
users = sqlalchemy.Table('users', db_metadata,
    Column('id', sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('username', sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True),
    # add rest of your table schema here...
)
```

Comment: I would like to avoid putting raw sql in my code so I am safe from sql injections.

Comment: updated to use `select` method instead of `text`.  Check out [sqlalchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#selecting) for more info